# Can't load data to make dataframes and query with SQL

Tags: r, sqlite

I am new to R and work with MSSQL for over a year now. I need to import an excelfile with two sheets into Rstudio so I can make dataframes and write querys. I've got an error and can't figure out why..

Can anyone here spot the line(s) causing the error? I've added 2 printscreens, one with the code, one with the sheets.

The sheets that need to be imported:

[image]

The code:

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use the `readxl` or `XLConnect` packages to read the excel file directly?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

R cannot read your query directly, you have to write your query inside a `dbGetQuery()` function.

```
dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM covid")
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I still get an error:

Error: near "dbGetQuery": syntax error
Failed to execute SQL chunk

Comment: Probably because you haven't established the connection properly. Make sure your connection is valid and you have access to the tables in dataset by `dbReadTables(con)`.